# How to clone TFS to GitHub with history using Git-TFS?

Tags: github, tfs, git-tfs

I'm trying to clone a GIT repository in TFS using git-tfs using TFS 2012
`git tfs clone http://sourcecontrol.oldcompanyname.local:8080/tfs/foo $/companyname/myrepository . --b=all --resumable`

Gives me:
`error: the path $/companyname/myrepository you want to clone doesn't exist!`

I have an empty repository called /companyname/myrepository in my github account

*(the urls and names are genericized for the public post)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git TFS is for converting TFVC repositories to local Git repositories. It has nothing to do with GitHub. Once you have a local repo, you can add a GitHub remote and push it there.

The clone URL should be the path to your TFS instance, stopping at the project collection. `http://companyname.local:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`.

The next part is the path to a folder in the TFVC repository. If you have a team project named `Foo` and you want to clone the `Main` branch, you'd specify `$/Foo/Main`.

Comment: Ahhh - I was thinking the `$/Foo/Main` part was the repository in Github and not the TFS repository.  Working now - thanks!